# Load model stored as json file Keras

Tags: python, json, keras, data-science

I'm loading the model stored as json file using Keras library model_from_json. Following are the steps I'm executing

```
json_file = open('file.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

Its throwing me an error when I execute : `loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)`

Following is the error : TypeError: **init**() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

As per the documentation, I'm on the right track. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Appreciate any recommendations

Comment: Are you using the same Keras versions to produce JSON and load it?

Comment: Yes they are same

Comment: Then include the full traceback that generates this error.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Your code is correct and it should work, you can alternatively try:

```
with open('model_architecture.json', 'r') as f:
      model = model_from_json(f.read())
```

If this does not work, check your json file, it might me corrupt?

Comment: The model isn't loading successfully. When I run loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)  I'm getting the error.

Comment: @iprof0214 I updated the answer, could you try and check this, hope it helps!